# Why i can't get WP custom fields value or post ID via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I wrote a code that generate a link based on the visitor location and it worked perfectly but i discovered that the generated code get cached since i'm using a full page caching so i though to solve that issue i can use ajax to load that link. I used the below code which worked perfectly in getting some variables that i need such as location variable and link domain variable etc.. however i'm unable to get the WooCommerce custom field data or even the product id it just return blank.

I'm using this code to get the custom field which worked perfectly when used directly in function however can't get it to work in ajax

```
$uk_asin = get_post_meta(get_post()->ID, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );
```

I used that code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'affiliate_link_ajax', 11);
function affiliate_link_ajax() {    
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

             jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                action: 'getmyfunctionform1'
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response) {

                jQuery("#myResultsform1").html(response);

                }

        }); 
    });
</script> 
<!-- end Ajax call to getmyfunctionform1 smc 11-22-2013 -->

<div id="myResultsform1"></div>
<?php
}
```

and this code in funnctions.php as well

```
// Ajax Function to Load PHP Function myfunctionform1 smc 11/22/2013

add_action('wp_ajax_getmyfunctionform1', 'myfunctionform1');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getmyfunctionform1', 'myfunctionform1');

function myfunctionform1() { 
    $uk_asin = get_post_meta(get_post()->ID, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );
echo $uk_asin;
// Whatever php and or html you want outputed by the ajax call in template file

die(); } // important must use

// end Ajax Function to Load PHP Function myfunctionform1 smc 11/22/2013
```

I would really appreciate if the answer was simple since i'm still very new to coding

Comment: So you're using this line `$uk_asin = get_post_meta(get_post()->ID, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );` in your `myfunctionform1()` and it's not returning any value?

Comment: @Michael Yes exactly, also when i try to request product id in ajax that doesn't return value, However, if I defined a variable like
$var1 = 'Hello World!';
echo $var1;
it returns value in ajax using the above code

Comment: I don't think this: `get_post()->ID` will work in your AJAX callback. You have to either pass an ID or a post object to the function, otherwise it uses the global `$post`, which will not be present during your AJAX call I assume. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

Comment: @Michael Could you please tell me how to pass the id or that custom field value to this function, I'm sorry I very new to coding.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: But why do you actually want to get the meta value by AJAX? Can't you just get it directly in your `affiliate_link_ajax()` callback?

Comment: @Michael One last thing, please
Here you can see the page that has the ajax button working nicely but the button takes about 2.5 seconds to appear, is there anything i can do to make it appear faster?

Comment: Check your browser console, if the XHR-Request takes 2.5 seconds to complete then there's an issue with your server response time maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your post ID to your AJAX request:

```
data: {
    action: 'getmyfunctionform1',
    postId: <?php echo get_post()->ID; ?>
}
```

And then use it in your callback function to get the meta value:

```
function myfunctionform1() { 
    $postId = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'postId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $uk_asin = get_post_meta( $postId, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Michael. it worked for me now, I just was wondering what you meant by saying "get it directly in your affiliate_link_ajax() callback" do you mean to put that line
$uk_asin = get_post_meta(get_post()->ID, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );

into affiliate_link_ajax() and then on  myfunctionform1()  echo $uk_asin   
I tried to do that but didn't work for me not sure why

Comment: What I meant is why don't you just echo your link in `affiliate_link_ajax()` directly? Why do you need to make an AJAX call to get it?

Comment: well the link I need to serve for the client is based on the client location, actually i already made your suggestion and it worked perfectly but then i discovered that because i'm using full page caching if the first visitor was from France he will get amazon.fr link and then if someone from Italy visited the website he will get amazon.fr link too instead of Amazon.its links... so i though that ajax could solve that issue